# How to parse an embedded template in Go?

Tags: go, embed, go-templates

I'm trying to write a Go program that generates code and to use the [`embed`](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) package together with [`ParseFS`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.ParseFS) to parse the template. The code should ultimately satisfy the requirement that it can be run from any directory in the repository.

So far, I have the following working implementation using `ParseFiles`. Using this directory structure,

```
.
├── codegen
│   └── main.go
├── foo
│   ├── foo.go
│   ├── foo.go.tmpl
│   └── foo_test.go
├── gen
│   └── foo.go
└── go.mod
```

The `foo.go` file contains the code generation code,

```golang
package foo

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "path/filepath"
)

const templateFile = "../foo/foo.go.tmpl"

type GeneratedType struct {
    Name         string
    StringFields []string
}

func GenerateCode() ([]byte, error) {
    tmpl, err := template.New(filepath.Base(templateFile)).ParseFiles(templateFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("parse template: %v", err)
    }

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    if err := tmpl.Execute(&buf, GeneratedType{
        Name:         "Foo",
        StringFields: []string{"Bar"},
    }); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("execute template: %v", err)
    }

    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

where the template `foo.go.tmpl` is

```
package foo

type {{.Name}} struct {
    {{- range .StringFields}}
    {{.}} string
    {{- end}}
}
```

It also has a unit test, `foo_test.go`:

```golang
package foo

import (
    "go/format"
    "testing"
)

func TestGenerateCode(t *testing.T) {
    code, err := GenerateCode()
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("generate code: %v", err)
    }

    if _, err := format.Source(code); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("format source code: %v", err)
    }
}
```

The `codegen/main.go` contains is run with Go's generate feature and contains the invocation of `GenerateCode` that generates code in an output directory `gen`:

```golang
//go:generate go run github.com/khpeek/codegen-example/codegen
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/khpeek/codegen-example/foo"
)

func main() {
    code, err := foo.GenerateCode()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("generate code: %v", err)
    }

    if err := os.Mkdir("../gen", 0700); err != nil && !errors.Is(err, os.ErrExist) {
        log.Fatalf("create directory for generated code: %v", err)
    }

    if err := os.WriteFile("../gen/foo.go", code, 0644); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("write file: %v", err)
    }
}
```

This works in that I can call both `go generate ./...` and `go test ./...` to generate the code and run tests successfully. However, it is a bit fragile because the template file path `../foo/foo.go.tmpl` only "coincidentally" resolves correctly from both the `codegen` and the `foo` directory. If I were to change the directory level, I suspect this example would no longer work.

I would like to make this more robust by using the `embed` package so that I'm always referencing files in the package directory (`foo` in this case). To that end, I attempted to change `foo.go` into the following:

```golang
package foo

import (
    "bytes"
    "embed"
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
)

//go:embed foo.go.tmpl
var templateFS embed.FS

type GeneratedType struct {
    Name         string
    StringFields []string
}

func GenerateCode() ([]byte, error) {
    tmpl, err := template.New("foo.go.tmpl").ParseFS(templateFS)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("parse template: %v", err)
    }

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    if err := tmpl.Execute(&buf, GeneratedType{
        Name:         "Foo",
        StringFields: []string{"Bar"},
    }); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("execute template: %v", err)
    }

    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

Now however, when I try to generate code or run unit tests I get a `no files name in call to ParseFiles` error:

```
> go generate ./...
2023/01/31 09:06:21 generate code: parse template: template: no files named in call to ParseFiles
exit status 1
codegen/main.go:1: running "go": exit status 1
```

```
> go test ./...
?       github.com/khpeek/codegen-example/codegen   [no test files]
--- FAIL: TestGenerateCode (0.00s)
    foo_test.go:11: generate code: parse template: template: no files named in call to ParseFiles
FAIL
FAIL    github.com/khpeek/codegen-example/foo   0.137s
?       github.com/khpeek/codegen-example/gen   [no test files]
FAIL
```

Can anyone explain why `ParseFS` isn't "finding" the template file?

Comment: [`ParseFS`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template@go1.19.5#Template.ParseFS) has a second variadic parameter. Try to provide an argument for that parameter. You can use a glob pattern if you don't want to be too literal.

Answer (score 2):

To convert [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)'s comment to an answer, I needed to provide a second, variadic argument to `ParseFS` representing a glob pattern that would match the template file:

```golang
tmpl, err := template.New("foo.go.tmpl").ParseFS(templateFS, "*.go.tmpl")
```